# Node.js promises and error handling. Can this not be done cleaner?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I'm new to writing node.js and having a problem with some messy code. I don't know necessarily if it is messy, maybe I'm just not used to node code.

Anyway, the code works, but I'm a little bit unsure about my error handling, like what happens when some of the promises fail. I try to do a rollback/release in the catch step, but I'm not sure if this is ok.

Also. Is it possible to write this code cleaner?

```
function insertAnAddress(){ 
 var address = {
     country : "A country",
     city : "A city",
     street : "Random",
     number : 6,
     postalcode : "A789",
     province : "a province"
   }

  dbpool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
       beginTransaction(connection)
          .then( () => {
                     return insertAddress(address,connection);
          })
         .then((rows) => {
                       console.log(rows);
               return commitTransaction(connection)
         })
         .then(()=>{
              connection.release();
              })
         .catch((err) => {
              //If rollback fails, the connection will not be released.
              //also, is it a good idea to try and do the rollback/release here in the catch?
              connection.rollback(() => {
                  connection.release();
              });
              throw err;
         });
    });
});


function beginTransaction(connection){
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  connection.beginTransaction( (err) => {
    if (err) {reject(err);}
    resolve();
  })});
}


function insertAddress(address,connection) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
     // Do async job
        connection.query('INSERT INTO address (country,city,Street,number,postalcode,province) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)', [address.country,'4','5',6,'7','8'] , (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {reject(err);}

            resolve(rows);

        })
    })
}

function commitTransaction(connection) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
   // Do async job
   connection.commit(function(err) {
      if (err) {reject(err);}
      resolve();
})})}
```

Comment: To clean it up a little bit, you can use `async/await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

A couple recommendations:

1) Use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert callback style to Promise style, instead of the Promise constructor

2) When an arrow function consists of a single return statement, drop the curly braces and return keyword.

3) Use `finally` to release the connection whether or not there was an error.

Result:

```
const util = require('util');

function insertAnAddress(){ 
 var address = {
     country : "A country",
     city : "A city",
     street : "Random",
     number : 6,
     postalcode : "A789",
     province : "a province"
   }

  dbpool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
       beginTransaction(connection)
         .then( () => insertAddress(address,connection) )
         .then((rows) => {
               console.log(rows);
               return commitTransaction(connection);
         })
         .catch(util.promisify(connection.rollback.bind(connection)))
         .finally( () => connection.release() );
    });
});


function beginTransaction(connection){
 return util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction.bind(connection))();
}


function insertAddress(address,connection) {
    return util.promisify(connection.query.bind(connection))(
      'INSERT INTO address (country,city,Street,number,postalcode,province) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',
      [address.country,'4','5',6,'7','8']
    );
}

function commitTransaction(connection) {
  return util.promisify(connection.commit.bind(connection))();
}
```

You could also get rid of all the `util.promisify` calls by using a library that wraps the `mysql` library like [mysql-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise), or better IMO, by using a Promise library like [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) which has a [promisifyAll](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) function.

Comment: Note that `promise.finally` is only supported by node 10.0 or using `--harmony-promise-finally` in >=8.1.4, unless he's using a promise library.